# Why is mysql workbench editor is so slow when working on a slow network?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded from Mysql workbench 5.x to 6.0.7.11215, And I am noticing strange slowness problem.

Whenever I try to edit the query, move the cursor around, or just try to add any characters, the editor hangs for a bit for a few seconds, and then resume normally.

This only happens when I am using a slow network connection to the server.

This issue was never there in the old Mysql workbench verison 5.x.

I disabled autocomplete, and restarted the program, but the issue is still there.

I used wireshark to examine the network traffic, and noticed a few of SSH packets at the time of the slowness, but I can't really know what is in them since, since the packets are encrypted. (it is worth noting that I am using database connection over an ssh tunnel)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Mysql workbench is not a general software, it is a dedicated tool for mysql database manipulation.

Comment: Unless you have a **specific** programming question that goes along with your network problem, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, questions on programming tools are absolutely on-topic on SO.  (and this has nothing to do with a "network" problem -- even if it's the network that is exacerbating the user experience)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the slowness happens because of the context help. This feature queries the server's help tables to get help information for a specific topic that MySQL Workbench derives from the current caret position. Try this: hide the context help pane (activate snippet tab or hide the right side bar). If that context help pane is not visible no help queries are sent.

For more information about the context help see my blog post here: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/08/mysql-workbench-6-0-help-is-on-the-way/

Comment: Thanks, it drove me nuts! One note however: on 6.0.9 version simply hiding right pane didn't help - context help was fetched anyway (well, at least the slowdown was still there). I had to switch to 'Snippets'.

Comment: In the upcomming release (currently in public beta) this task is done in a background thread to avoid blocking the UI. Give it a shoot (http://mysqlworkbench.org).

Answer (score 1):

work around: in the query place some extra comma by which the current line becomes x- in red colour
do all the editing ;
it won't go hang state
finally remove comma   and execute

Answer (score 0):

Set limit rows in query results to 1000 go in: Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Queries and check the limit to 1000 
Workbench 6.1